# Connect To Oracle DB Via JDBC Driver

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection, ojdbc

I'm trying to connect Oracle database using this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/). 
It is working when I use command line: ***java -cp c:\jdbc-test\ojdbc6.jar;c:\jdbc-test OracleJDBC***
I have put ojdbc6.jar in the same folder with OracleJDBC.java.
Now I need to run it on Eclipse, but it gives me an error:

**Output:**
*Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)   at
>   OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:32)*

Is it because of **ojdbc6.jar** location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the library in the *project build path*.

- Right click on project
- Build Path
- Go to Libraries Tab
- Add external jar (ODBC jar) there

[image: Right Click on project for Build Path option]

[image: Java Build Path libraries configuration]

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep the jar file in external library
follow this way

1. right click on your project
2. click "build path"
3. click "configure build path"
4. click "library " tab
5. click "add external jars"
6. give the path of the jar file

Then run it
Please see the screenshots
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **ojdbc6.jar** into classpath of your application.